# Physics of exercising and forces felt

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, biology

Let's imagine an ideal scenario where you're lifting your own weight in its entirety. Let's say a woman weighing $100$ lbs. Suppose she's doing an idealized handstand and pushup from that position. So she's lifting $100$ lbs. Let's say ideally all of the forces are on her arms only. Do these forces on her arm increase or decrease due to momentum? So as she moves downward, the speed and the mass of the woman change the force she feels?

She would just feel $F=ma$ she was only doing the handstand. But how about while she's moving downward and then up? How do I figure this out?